# How to change the visual aspects of the xaxis, which consists of dates?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm reading some data with pandas and trying to plot them. 
Now, I'd like to change the visual aspects of the x-axis tick labels: the yticks and xlabel is changing, but not the xticks.
I'd like to make my xticks, red, bold and larger, just like the yticks.

But for some reason, the code doesn't change them. What is going wrong?

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

plt.rcParams["font.weight"] = "bold"
plt.rcParams["axes.labelweight"] = "bold"
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 10})

model_obs = pd.read_csv("select_obs_data2.csv", sep=',')

print(model_obs.head(4))
model_obs['correlation'] = model_obs['real_obs'].corr(model_obs['Value'])
model_obs.iloc[1:, 6] = np.nan

model_obs['bias^2'] = (model_obs['Value'] - model_obs['real_obs']) ** 2
model_obs['RMS'] = model_obs['bias^2'].mean()
model_obs.iloc[1:, 8] = np.nan
model_obs.drop(['bias^2'], axis=1, inplace=True)
model_obs.drop(['time'], axis=1, inplace=True)

fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots()
locs = "upperleft"
model_obs["date"] = pd.to_datetime(model_obs["date"])
print(type(model_obs['date']))
print(model_obs["date"].dt.month)

model_obs.plot(x='date', y='Value', figsize=(16, 7), ax=ax2, style='--', label='Model')
model_obs.plot(x='date', y='real_obs', figsize=(16, 7), ax=ax2, label='Observation')

plt.legend(loc='upper right', prop={'size': 12})
ax2.xaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=15)
ax2.yaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=15)
ax2.set_xlabel('Date Time', fontsize=10, fontweight='bold')
ax2.set_ylabel('Sea Level (m)', fontsize=15, fontweight='bold')
ax2.tick_params(labelcolor='r', labelsize='large', width=8)

plt.show()
```

[image]

```
# x axis data
# model_obs['date']
0     2019-09-01 01:00:00
1     2019-09-01 02:00:00
2     2019-09-01 03:00:00
3     2019-09-01 04:00:00
4     2019-09-01 05:00:00
5     2019-09-01 06:00:00
6     2019-09-01 07:00:00
7     2019-09-01 08:00:00
8     2019-09-01 09:00:00
9     2019-09-01 10:00:00
10    2019-09-01 11:00:00
11    2019-09-01 12:00:00
12    2019-09-01 13:00:00
13    2019-09-01 14:00:00
14    2019-09-01 15:00:00
15    2019-09-01 16:00:00
16    2019-09-01 17:00:00
17    2019-09-01 18:00:00
966   2019-10-11 07:00:00
967   2019-10-11 08:00:00
968   2019-10-11 09:00:00
969   2019-10-11 10:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

The tick labels are not changing, because they are minor ticks. Default, [`tick_params()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html) operates only on the major ticks. There are two optional parameters that control this:

- `axis : {'x', 'y', 'both'}`, default is 'both', so operating on both axis
- `which : {'major', 'minor', 'both'}`, default is 'major', so only having effect on the major ticks

`tick_params()` can be called multiple times to set the visual aspects of x, y, major or minor ticks individually.

For example, to set the major ticks red and the minor ticks blue:

```py
ax2.tick_params(labelcolor='r', labelsize='large', width=8, which='major')
ax2.tick_params(labelcolor='b', labelsize='large', width=8, which='minor')
```

[image: resulting tick labels]

Comment: Did this answer your question?